# Realtime database authentication: failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I would like to use these rules from the [security quickstart guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/quickstart)

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Although I do not understand where the `auth.uid` is read from?

I can get it to store information when I do the below so I can confirm the problem is with `auth.id`. I'm not sure if I need to pass that as a parameter or something? I'm afraid this is where I am lost.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": true,
        ".write": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is the current java code I am using to test it with:

```
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();
User u = new User("Jack", "jack@email.co.uk", "12345678"); // Very simple class holding this user information
myRef.child("users").child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(u);
```

I've been looking at information on firebases real time database but every time they get to the authentication they just say "For now we will turn off authentication but make sure you use it in production!".

Comment: To learn about the `auth` variable in your security rules, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/user-security#section-variable. It's automatically populated once a user signs in and in that contains a `uid` property that is the unique identifier for the signed in user.

Comment: The code you shared doesn't authenticate the user, so this rule will fail `$uid === auth.uid`. To learn how to sign in users, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Comment: Yes sorry, so I have a LoginActivity which authenticates the sets the intent to this activity. I believe the problem may be that I'm authenticating the user in a different activity and it is somehow losing its "authenticated" state

Comment: Firebase Authentication state is persisted across activities. But `mFirebaseUser` might not be. Without seeing the [minimal, complete code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it is hard to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bloody idiot,

I was calling `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` a few lines above my code which I originally put in for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need to pass as a parameter, firebase do it for you. Let me try to explain, after you create a user in your console and login in your application, firebase will provide each user with a different `uid` (similar to this `ca07912b-7e65-41ad-8342-e87cf6f6ceb2`).

So after you login it will be stored in your smartphone and every request that you do in the database firebase will analyse your security rules, so when you are saying that only the owner of the uid **X** can access `/users/**X**/..` then if you are not logged in you don't have permission to read neither to write on this path.